# Add button relative to cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets where I have some data in the range `M1:O2`. The width of those three columns can vary from sheet to sheet, but the button should get added to every single sheet without overlapping the data. So instead of using the typical way like this:

`Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(690, 4, 173.25, 41.25)`

I would like to add the button relative to cell, in my case cell `Q1` or `Q2`. Is that possible? Or can I find out where cell `Q1` is located (i.e.  double values for `left` and `top`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every range (a cell is a range) has properties like `left` and `top` (and `width` and `height`).

```
Dim r as Range
set r = ws.range("Q1")
Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(r.left, r.top, 173.25, 41.25)
' To fit the button exactly into the cell, use:
' Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(r.left, r.top, r.width, r.height)
' To ensure that the button stays always in the cell, use:
btn.Placement = xlMove
```